# How to display message with the help of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m trying to do a validation using jquery.
Enter Account no:

here is my html code

```
<input type="text" name="Assets" id="Assets" size="25" /><br />
<div id="eb"> Please Enter Valid Account no </div>
Enter Amount<input type="text" name="Liability" id="Liability" size="25" /><br />
```

and here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Assets").change(function(){
        var Assets = $('input#Assets').val();
        var expression=/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{10}/;
        if (Assets == "" || Assets == " ") {
            $('#eb').show();
        }
        else if(Assets.test(expression)){
            $('#eb').hide();
        }
        $('#eb').toggle();
}
```

i want to display a mesage when user write a account no then at a time he can see the message that Please Enter Valid Account no and if he insert correct then that message can be hide.

here is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BzdfN/5/
please help

Comment: By default error message should be displayed and if the account number is valid then it should be hidden...Is it so??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Assets").change(function () {
        var Assets = this.value;
        var expression = /[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{10}/;
        if (Assets.match(expression)) {  
            $('#eb').hide();
        } else {
            $('#eb').show();
        }
    });
});
```

This is a suggestion for more simple code. Notice I used  [**match()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which takes a regex as paramenter, if you want to use [**test()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) you should use the value/string as paramenter and use like `expression.test(Assets)`.

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/evAr7/)

About your code/fiddle:

- you missed adding jQuery library to the fiddle
- you missed `)` closing the change() function
- you missed `})` closing the ready() function
- you used `test()` with wrong order, check my text above about `match()` and `test()`
- your fiddle with corrections: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cuNyW/)

Comment: there isn't any message in your fiddle?

Comment: @nrsharma, I made a new version.

Comment: if i am insert 56f in first textbox then it should display error message without enter into second text box.is it possible. i know this is silly question but i am very new to jquery

Comment: @SanjayRathod, it already does, but only when you click away and apply the change. Otherwise you should use keyup event like this: http://jsfiddle.net/evAr7/1/

Comment: validation completed in my fiddle buut still there is one problem. i want that if user not inserting any value and go for a next textbox by pressing tab then he or she can be see error message.how to do this

Comment: @SanjayRathod maybe you want to use the blur event.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery was not included and multiple syntax errors

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var expression = /[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{10}/;
    $("#Assets").change(function () {
        $('#eb').toggle(!expression.test(this.value));
    })
})//missing brackets
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gK828/)

Comment: if i am insert 56f in first textbox then it should display error message without enter into second text box.is it possible. i know this is silly question but i am very new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/BzdfN/9/  I made a bunch of changes, including activating jQuery, closing some functions, and reversed Assets and expression for the .test call

```
        else if(expression.test(Assets)){
```

Comment: if i am insert 56f in first textbox then it should display error message without enter into second text box.is it possible. i know this is silly question but i am very new to jquery

Comment: If I understand the question right, you want it updated every time a key is pressed instead of when leaving the text box?  Just update .change to .keyup.  Like here - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/BzdfN/24/

Comment: I have implemented http://jsfiddle.net/F6c5U/1/ but this is not working when i am implementing in localhost.

Comment: So it works on JSfiddle but not on your own computer you say?